# Is there any way to validate only part of the XML structure against the schema server side?

Tags: xml, web-services, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd

Is there any way to validate only part of the XML structure against the schema server side?

I have an XSD - using this XSD, I can create the XML. If there is no client-side validation then a marshalling error is thrown for an incorrect XML. I need to prevent this by enabling server-side schema validation on certain parts of the XML. As the XML is too generic, I cannot apply the validation to the entire XML.

for example : --

```
@WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="cartStatus")
    @RequestWrapper(localName="addToCart", className="addToCart")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName="addToCartResponse", className="addToCartResponse")
    public OperationStatus addToCart(  
                            @WebParam(name="cart", targetNamespace="")
                            @XmlElement(required=true)
                            Cart cos, 
                            @WebParam(name="cartoptions", targetNamespace="")
                            @XmlElement(required=false)
                            CartOptions options) throws OrderServiceException ;
```

if i want to perform a server side validation CartOptions object how to achieve this part, instead of marshalling error my user defined exception to be thrown

Comment: can you share some details like xml and the schema.

Comment: @Sikorski update the code with the comments

Comment: just curious, is it Spring Web framework ? and i asked for xml and schema :)

Comment: @Sikorski yes, we are using java2wsdl approach, so i need to enforce my schema validation on my POJO.